# "Attempted to read past the end of the stream" in SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, excel, zip

I have a bug in a production system, when a user select an excel (.xlsx) file to upload inside the software, the application throws an exception: `Attempted to read past the end of the stream. -    at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipHelperStream.ReadLEShort()`

I'm using `ExcelDataReader`, with SharpZipLib updated to 0.65.
Anyone have a idea?

ExcelDataReader Extract Method that uses SharpZipLib:
Exception was throwed in zipFile = new ZipFile(filestream);

Thanks.

```
public bool Extract(Stream fileStream)

    {
        if (null == fileStream) return false;

        CleanFromTemp();

        NewTempPath();

        _isValid = true;

        ZipFile zipFile = null;

        try
        {
            zipFile = new ZipFile(fileStream);

            IEnumerator enumerator = zipFile.GetEnumerator();

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry)enumerator.Current;

                ExtractZipEntry(zipFile, entry);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _isValid = false;
            _exceptionMessage = ex.Message;
            Log.Trace(string.Format("{0} - {1}",ex.Message ,ex.StackTrace), this.GetType());

            CleanFromTemp();
        }
        finally
        {
            fileStream.Close();

            if (null != zipFile) zipFile.Close();
        }

        return _isValid ? CheckFolderTree() : false;
    }
```

Comment: What is the code that results in this exception?

Comment: Have you checked the excel file ? perhaps it is corruct or uses some ActiveX components (OLE...) etc. ?

Comment: @oleksii, the exception was throwed by this code: "zipFile = new ZipFile(fileStream);"

Comment: Can you post this and surrounding code as well? Seems like the `fileStream` has been read by some other code already. Can you double check that nobody read the stream before?

Comment: @Yahia, it's a simple excel file, user can open it without problems.

Comment: When a copy the file for the first time, inside U:\, and try to load file inside my application, i got a error: "Cannot open file because its being used by another process", but nobody are reading the file, and if a try for the second time, the file will be imported, very strange...

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the zip file does not follow the ZIP standard. There is something in that xlsx file that is throwing off the decompressor.

You can try and use another zip library (or check for updates of the existing library [0.86 is the current build](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx)) and use that to decompress the file in to a stream, unfortunately I do not have a recommendation of other libraries to try as the time I had to fix the same issue I was able to just fix the zip header instead of finding a new zip library.